# Flask REST API returns 400 response when hosted, but 200 when deployed locally

Tags: rest, flask, google-cloud-platform, deployment, python-requests

I'm trying to host a Flask REST API on Google Cloud. I've tested all my endpoints prior to deployment, and they all worked fine. However, when I actually deployed the endpoints, the GET and POST methods suddenly stopped working. Which is weird, because PUT still works. Weirder still, I get a 400 error for the GET method and a 500 error for the POST method, even though I did not code them to return these if there is an actual error with the query. The following are the **broken endpoints**:

```py
@app.route("/user/get_profile", methods=["GET"])
def get_profile():
    data = request.get_json()
 
    if "email" in data:
        email = data["email"]
        if email:
            user = supabase.table("User Subscriptions").select("*").eq("email", email).single().execute()
            return jsonify(user.data)
    else:
        return Response('{"message": "Email is required"}', status=401)

@app.route("/user/sign_up", methods=["POST"])
def sign_up():
    '''Remember to block people from signing up using the same email.'''
    data = request.get_json()

    # Check if email is inputted
    if "email" in data:
        email = data["email"]
    else:
        return Response('{"message": "Email is required"}', status=401)

    # If user is already signed up (check using email), reject
    user = supabase.table("User Subscriptions").select("*").eq("email", email).single().execute()
    if user.data:
        return Response('{"message": "User already exists"}', status=401)

    newUser = {
        "email": email,
        "subscription_level": "basic",
        "remaining_tokens": 10000,
        "theme": "light",
        "logged_in": False
    }
    supabase.table("User Subscriptions").insert(newUser).execute()
    return Response('{"message": "Sign up successful"}')
```

These two, however, still **work fine**, so I know it's not a problem with the database connection:

```py
@app.route("/user/login", methods=["PUT"])
def login():
    '''
    Check if user exists. If not, return message to sign up first.
    If user logs in successfully, change user subscriptions parameter "logged_in" to True (bool)
    '''
    data = request.get_json()

    # Check if email and password are both inputted
    if "email" in data:
        email = data["email"]
    else:    
        return Response('{"message": "Email is required"}', status=401)
    if "password" in data:
        password = data["password"]
    else:
        return Response('{"message": "Password is required"}', status=401)
    
    # Check if user is signed up
    user = supabase.table("User Subscriptions").select("*").eq("email", email).single().execute()
    if not user.data:
        return Response('{"message": "Sign up is required"}', status=401)

    # Check if input email and password are authorized
    # user = supabase.auth.sign_in(email=email, password=password)
    supabase.table("User Subscriptions").update({"logged_in": True}).eq("email", email).execute()
    return Response('{"message": "Login successful"}')


@app.route("/user/logout", methods=["PUT"])
def logout():
    data = request.get_json()
    if "email" in data:
        email = data["email"]
    else:
        return Response('{"message": "Email is required"}', status=401)

    supabase.table("User Subscriptions").update({"logged_in": False}).eq("email", email).execute()
    return Response('{"message": "Logout successful"}')
```

I've been testing using the requests library and some basic inputs. It all works fine locally, but for the deployed url (pelagic-diorama), the two don't work.

```py
import requests

# BASE = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
BASE = "https://pelagic-diorama-357301.uk.r.appspot.com/"

query = {
    "email": "hie@gmail.com",
    "password": "asdasd"
}

# Returns <Response [400]>
response = requests.get(BASE + "user/get_profile", json=query)
print(response)

# Works fine
query = {
    "email": "hie@gmail.com",
    "password": "asdasd"
}
response = requests.put(BASE + "user/login", json=query).json()
print(response)

# Works fine
response = requests.put(BASE + "user/logout", json=query).json()
print(response)

query = {
    "email": "yoyo@gmail.com",
    "password": "asdasd",
    "subscription_level": "pro",
    "logged_in": False
}

# Returns <Response [500]>
response = requests.post(BASE + "user/sign_up", json=query)
print(response)
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious that has to do with the difference between deployment and hosting locally, but I'm not sure what. Please help.

Comment: FYI, you can try the test script (last code chunk) yourself, since the endpoints are hosted.

Comment: the best way to figure out why stuff isn't working on App Engine is to check the logs. See [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface) for reference

Comment: I did check the logs, but for some reason, the 400 errors didn't even show up.